# Jenkins build fails with "Treating warnings as errors because of process.env.CI = true"

Tags: maven, jenkins, npm, build, continuous-integration

After updating the Jenkins, all builds started to fail with the following errors.

```
[ERROR] {some text}: {some text} is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
[INFO] Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
[INFO] Most CI servers set it automatically.
```

How can I fix this for all builds?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a result of this change:

> https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-36707

It has introduced the standard `CI` env var that is always set to `true` in order to allow pipelines and tools to know they're executing in a continuous integration context.

This has emerged as a best practice used by most other popular CI solutions, and a number of tools look for this variable in order to make CI-appropriate optimizations.

You can set `CI` env variable to false through `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure System` > `Global properties` section.
[image]

Add a new env variable `CI` with the value `false`.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your build uses a Jenkinsfile, you may prefer to add

```
    environment {
        CI = false          // do not treat warnings as errors
    }
```

to it, allowing the build to work independent from the Jenkins configuration.